# Error: Argument type 'Date?' does not conform to expected type 'ReferenceConvertible'

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I am getting an error in Xcode:

> Argument type 'Date?' does not conform to expected type
>   'ReferenceConvertible'

What does this error mean? And how to fix it?

**EXAMPLE:**

I have an Entity in Core Data with a name ToDoItem (Codegen: Class Definition and Module: Current Product Module) and set 2 attributes:

1. createdAt - NOT optional, default value: current date
2. title - NOT optional, default value: empty string

Xcode automatically generated class for me:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class ToDoItem: NSManagedObject {

}
```

In ContentView I have this code where I am passing todoItem to EditItemView:

```
ForEach(toDoItems, id: \.self) {todoItem in

    NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(todoItem: todoItem)) {

        ToDoItemView(title: todoItem.title ?? "", createdAt: todoItem.createdAt ?? Date())
}
```

And in EditItemView I am getting the error on this line:

```
Text("\(todoItem.createdAt, formatter: Self.dateFormat)")
```

I can make this error go away if I use:

```
Text("\(todoItem.createdAt!, formatter: Self.dateFormat)")
```

But... even now there's no error while building app, after I delete a todoItem using Delete button in my app, the app crashes on the same exact line with error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

I am just learning and so far I know this is related to some values being optional in Swift even if they are not optional in Core Data. And I read that unwrapping optional values with ! should be avoided most of the times. But still, I don't know how to fix this problem. How to use todoItem.createdAt if todoItem.createdAt doesn't work and todoItem.createdAt! crashes the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force unwrap unconditionally is bad thing, actually you now know why, try to avoid it always...

Here is one of possible fixes for that crash:

```
Text(todoItem.createdAt != nil ? "\(todoItem.createdAt!, formatter: Self.dateFormat)" : "")
```